# Why 'x = x + something' does not return the same result as 'x += something'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function `sprout_leaves` that sprouts new leaves containing the data in leaves at each leaf in the original tree t and return the resulting tree.

So, the output would be something like this

```
>>> t1 = tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3)])
>>> print_tree(t1)
1
  2
  3
>>> new1 = sprout_leaves(t1, [4, 5])
>>> print_tree(new1)
1
  2
    4
    5
  3
    4
    5

>>> t2 = tree(1, [tree(2, [tree(3)])])
>>> print_tree(t2)
1
  2
    3
>>> new2 = sprout_leaves(t2, [6, 1, 2])
>>> print_tree(new2)
1
  2
    3
      6
      1
      2
```

Now my function looks like this:

```
def sprout_leaves(t, leaves):

    leaves_as_tree = branches(tree('', [tree(x) for x in leaves]))


    if not is_leaf(t):
    
        for b in branches(t):
            if is_leaf(b):
                b += leaves_as_tree  # !!! 
            else:
                return tree(label(t),[(sprout_leaves(tree(label(b), branches(b)), leaves))])
    return t
```

This function returns the desired result for me:

```
>>> t1 = tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3)])
>>> new1 = sprout_leaves(t1, [4, 5])
>>> print_tree(new1)
1
  2
    4
    5
  3
    4
    5
```

However, if I change `b += leave_as_tree` to `b = b + leaves_as_tree`, the output changes to:

```
>>> t1 = tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3)])
>>> new1 = sprout_leaves(t1, [4, 5])
>>> print_tree(new1)
1
  2
  3
```

My question is simply: why is that? No matter what I try, if I don't use `+=`, the output would be wrong.

To reproduce this example, here are the functions needed:

https://codeshare.io/adqo6M

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of how we can reproduce this..

Comment: So if we replace `b += leaves_as_tree` with `b = b + leaves_as_tree` it fails? What is `branches` is it returning a `list`?

Comment: Specifically, what are `tree`, `branches`, `is_leaf` and `label`?

Comment: Or better yet, make an entirely new script that exhibits this behaviour;  You do not need 4 new classes to identify a simple behaviour.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b = b + leaves_as_tree` does a few things:

- Calls `b.__add__(leaves_as_tree)`
- Assigns the result of that operation to the name `b`. Now `b` points at a different object than it did before.

`b += leaves_as_tree` is different:

- It calls `b.__iadd__(leaves_as_tree)`
- ...and that's it.

So the real difference is that `b = b + leaves_as_tree` creates a new object and then updates `b` to point to it, but `b += leaves_as_tree` calls a function that mutates b in place.

(Note: there's nothing magical about `object.__iadd__` that *must* mutate the object in place, but if some class defined it to do something different, everyone would be annoyed with the author of that class.)

Here's an example using the builtin `list` class:

```
>>> a = []
>>> id(a)
4315491720

>>> a += [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)  # This will still have the same ID as it did originally
4315491720

>>> a = a + [4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> id(a)  # Now it will have a different ID because of the assignment operation
4315489736
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide a full example, it's impossible to say with certainty.

However, the `+=` operator uses a class' `__iadd__(self, other)` method, if available, otherwise it uses `__add__(self, other)`. The `+` operator always uses the `__add__(self, other)` method.

To clear up any confusion: `__add__()` gets you a different result because it returns a value, which can then be assigned (either to the same variable, or another - it's a new object regardless), while `__iadd__()` modifies the object it is called on.

So:

- `a += 1` executes as `a.__iadd__(1)`
   if `__iadd__()` is not available, it executes as `a = a.__add__(1)`
- `a = a + 1` executes as `a = a.__add__(1)`

Comment: It's the assignment operation (`b = ...`) that makes the difference, not `__add__` vs `__iadd__`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser I felt that was implied by the different way `__add__()` and `__iadd__()` work, but I suppose it could do with some more explanation. Added. Edit: actually, you are right that one sentence in there was wrong - removed that, thanks.